# Closure and Interior problem from Abbott's Analysis

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to show that $\overline{E}^c=(E^c)^\circ$. That is, the complement of the closure of $E$ is equivalent to the interior of the complement of $E$.
My attempt is this:
since $\overline{E}$ is closed, its complement is open. Since $E$ is open $\leftrightarrow E=E^\circ$, then this implies $\overline{E}^c=(\overline{E}^c)^\circ$. I'm not sure where to make progress from here.

Comment: Is it given that $E$ is open?

Comment: $E$ was not said to be open or closed.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $A$ is a closed set containing $E$ if and only if $A^c$ is an open set contained in $E^c$.

$\overline{E}$ is the intersection of all closed sets containing $E$. Then $\overline{E}^c$ is the complement of this set, namely the union of the complements of all closed sets containing $E$, in other words, the union of all open sets contained in $E^c$. But this is precisely the interior of $E^c$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $x\in {\overline E}^c\implies x\notin {\overline E}\implies  \exists r>0 $ such that $(x-r,x+r)\cap E\setminus \{x\}=\emptyset \implies (x-r,x+r)\subset X\setminus E\implies x\in (X\setminus E)^\circ$

try to see the reverse direction.