# Closure of a set in topological space

Tags: general-topology

Closure of a set $A$ in topological space $X$ is defined as intersection of all closed supersets of $A$.

Can we say that $Closure(A)= \bar{A}$ such that $(\bar{A})'=\bigcup B$ where $B$ is the class of open sets $C$ such that $C \cap A=\emptyset $

Comment: yes, try using Demorgan's law

Comment: Yes if $\bar{A}'$ denotes the complement of the closure of $A$. Quite often notation $B'$ is used for the [set of limitpoints](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Limit_point_of_a_set) of $B$. And what is "Closure(a)"? Your notation is kind of sloppy.

Comment: @drhab Thanks for the comment. I am new to topology , will work on notation.

Comment: Actually you should say: $B$ is the class of open sets $C$ such that $C\cap A=\varnothing$. Good luck with your topology.

Answer (score 2):

You should have a look at the notion of [interior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interior_%28topology%29).

For any set $A\subseteq X$, the interior $\operatorname{Int} A$ is the union of all open sets contained in $A$.

So what you wrote is that $\operatorname{Cl} A = X \setminus \operatorname{Int} (X\setminus A)$.

See also here:

- [Show that $Int(A)=X\setminus\overline{X\setminus A}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/872322/show-that-inta-x-setminus-overlinex-setminus-a)
- [Prove that the closure of complement, is the complement of the interior](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/970825/prove-that-the-closure-of-complement-is-the-complement-of-the-interior)
- https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1242256/prove-x-setminus-operatornamecla-operatornameintx-setminus-a
- [Closure and Interior problem from Abbott's Analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1443085/closure-and-interior-problem-from-abbotts-analysis)

(And probably many other posts...)